# 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromFile'

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a WPF app to show some images on my hard drive.
Here's my attempt :

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Photo
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Image myimage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\images\myimage.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get :

> 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for
>   'FromFile'

How can I get rid of this error? Thanks..

Comment: Which .NET Framework you use? It has belongs on only .NET 4 or higher.

Comment: It is .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Which `Image` class do you actually want to use, `System.Windows.Controls.Image` or `System.Drawing.Image`? The latter has that `FromFile` method but is based on GDI so you probably don't want to use that in a WPF application.

Comment: @Dirk I guess I should go with the first one, but can you tell how can I get image using the first one? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile(v=vs.110).aspx) is available with `System.Drawing.Image`. It is not available with `System.Windows.Controls.Image`. For WPF you shouldn't be using `System.Drawing.Image`.

So the question is how to load `Image` object  in WPF from a file. Use:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\images\myimage.jpg"));
```